# Best way for assigning max length for input type number

Tags: java, html, jquery, css, input

I am working on html inputs. I want an input (type number) to accept numbers with the maximum length of 5 like -99999 to 99999. I tried using maxLength attribute but it is allowing user to enter more than 5 digits. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: can you post the actual html code? maxlength should work. there's something else going on then.

Comment: Please add some code so I know if my answer is relevant or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `max` and `min` attribute of the input, like:

```
<input type="number" name="id" min="-99999" max="99999">
```

Then (depending on your styling) 2 arrows (up and down) will show and you won't be able to continue upping the number more than the max value and vice versa
[image]

You can learn more here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html-input-max-attribute

You can use form validation of some sort to show an alert if the user exceeds the limitation:
[image]

Comment: but user can enter more than 5 digits by directly entering by themselves

Comment: You can use form validation of some sort to show an alert if the user exceeds the limitation

Comment: I added an example of what that might look like

Comment: This is correct, i just want to remind @AbhiSingh that even with this kind of validation it's a good thing to validate again the data server-side, before saving it, it's easy to avoid client side validation on the browser and send non-validated data to the server